# How to keep only the last object in a RabbitMQ exchange?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I have a RabbitMQ exchange where I put quotes that change several times per second.

When a new message is sent to the exchange, I would like undelivered messages to be dropped and only the last one to be sent.

Is this possible?

I’m doing this in F# but an example in any language would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just configure the queue to have a max-length of 1.
When the queue gets a new message, it will delete any older messages that are waiting in the queue.

Comment: does this also work for an exchange? for a queue, I can pass: ["x-max-length", 1] but I can't see anything similar for the exchanges in the doc.

Comment: As far as I know, this can only be configured on the queue, not the exchange.

Comment: I passed it when creating an exchange and it works. In the admin tool, it shows the queue length attached to the exchange to be 1